# "open" command starts separate Emacs.app processes, or none at all

Tags: catalina, emacs

I recently moved to a MacBook Pro with Catalina from a different MBP running Mojave. I use Emacs.app from https://emacsformacosx.com/. For all previous Mac OS versions, the command

`open -a /Applications/Emacs.app myfile`

would, initially, start a new Emacs process and open my file; if Emacs was already open, it would open a new buffer for that file.

Now, in Catalina, it either (a) starts a completely new copy of Emacs with that file open, or sometimes, if Emacs is running already, (b) does nothing, neither of which is what I want.

Any ideas how to get the old behavior back?

Comment: Would `emacsclient` be an alternative?

Comment: For a variety of reasons, I like being able to e.g. drag and drop into the Emacs windows.

Comment: `emacsclient` just helps to load files from the command line into a running (or to be started) Emacs.app. You can still drag&drop as well.

Comment: In theory there should be a script on https://emacsformacosx.com/tips which does exactly that. In practice it's either missing or the web page somehow has a problem.

Comment: @nohillside `emacsclient` works great and should be the answer to this question, if you write the brief answer I will accept it.

Comment: @nohillside also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34940/setting-up-emacsclient-osx has more context for setting it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to use ˋemacsclientˋ:

- Add `(server-start)` to your `.emacs` file
- Run `emacsclient FILE` to open a file in a running Emacs